# How to write multiple when conditions using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get response when 3 conditions are satisfied otherwise it should reject and generate a failure response. below is my sample input:

```
 <Message>
    <Header>
    <Role actionCode="04">
                <RoleCode>BM01</RoleCode>
             </Role>
             <Role actionCode="04">
                <RoleCode>CM011</RoleCode>
             </Role>
    <Common>
   <tag>Data</tag>
   <tag2>Data2</tag2>
    <Pstatus>111</Pstatus>
    </Common>
    </Header>
    </Message>
```

I'm writing the condition as

```
<xsl:when test="$RoleCode = 'BM01 and CM011' and $Pstatus='111 OR 112' ">
<xsl:value-of select="$tag"/>
<xsl:when test="$RoleCode = 'BM02 and CM011' and $Pstatus='111 OR 112' ">
<xsl:value-of select="$tag2"/>
<xsl:when test="$Pstatus='101' ">Reject
<xsl:otherwise>Reject</xsl:otherwise>
```

When role code should match with BM01/BM02 and CM011 and also Pstatus as 111 or 112, then it should copy the data, if pstatus is 101 received, it should reject. I'm getting only reject message as output but conditions were not executing. Can someone please help on this ?

Comment: What is the variable $RoleCode bound to?

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.0

Comment: We are getting the input as shown in sample. My original XSLT and input is lengthy so I made short here. Got stuck using when condition.

Comment: We can't tell you how to test the value of variable $RoleCode without knowing what is in the variable.

Comment: I have given the path in my xslt by storing the value in a variable. But still didn't work me so I thought I have gone somewhere wrong using when condition.

Comment: Indeed, your when condition is badly wrong. But to fix it, we need to know what value you stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Message">
    <xsl:variable name="RoleCode" select="Header/Role/RoleCode" />
    <xsl:variable name="Pstatus" select="Header/Common/Pstatus" />
    <xsl:variable name="tag" select="Header/Common/tag" />
    <xsl:variable name="tag2" select="Header/Common/tag2" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$RoleCode='BM01' and $RoleCode='CM011' and ($Pstatus='111' or  $Pstatus='112')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$tag"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$RoleCode='BM02' and $RoleCode='CM011' and ($Pstatus='111' or  $Pstatus='112')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$tag2"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Reject</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```